# IntelliJ can't find "GL10" library for "Hello World" LibGDX Program

Tags: java, debugging, gradle, intellij-idea, libgdx

I am trying to teach myself libGDX, but the tutorial I was following gave an error when I tried to run it. I don't know enough LibGDX to make an MCVE, so I tried to find a simple "Hello World" program just to see if the problem was in my code or something else.

The problem is, the only "Hello World" program I was able to find can't seem to import a necessary libGDX library.

The library it can't import is `com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL10`. My IDE, IntelliJ-IDEA, says `can't resolve symbol 'GL10'` when I hover the cursor over it.

*How can I make this program run?*

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL10;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class HelloWorld implements ApplicationListener {
private SpriteBatch batch;
private BitmapFont font;

@Override
public void create() {
   batch = new SpriteBatch();
   font = new BitmapFont();
   font.setColor(Color.RED);
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
   batch.dispose();
   font.dispose();
}

@Override
public void render() {
   Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
   Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

   batch.begin();
   font.draw(batch, "Hello World", 200, 200);
   batch.end();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
}

@Override
public void pause() {
}

@Override
public void resume() {
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, OpenGL ES 1.x support was removed from libgdx so the interfaces GL10 and GL11 are no more. Try replacing `GL10` with `GL20`.

You can find the update notification at [OpenGL ES 1.x support removed from libgdx](https://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3311)

Comment: Thanks! That works! Or rather, it produces the same error I had last time. Which is a help I guess.

Comment: I just posted this question to find out if I was doing anything wrong. You can see the error I got at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54120420/libgdx-programs-always-throw-illegal-reflective-access-errors-when-running).